# How can I copy an XP Mode virtual machine from one computer to another?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-xp-mode

Is it possible to copy an XP Mode Virtual PC image from one computer to a completely different computer (not on the network, not related in any way whatsoever)?

I tried this, but it only would seem to work on the same computer:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/21904-virtual-xp-machine-copy.html

When I copy it to another computer and modify the settings as described above, the cursor just jumps around all over the screen and never starts.

Comment: Interesting.  You can definitely download prepackaged VMs for VirtualPC, like this [IE compatibility VM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en), which I have used.  So it must be possible.  There are a few potentially useful articles out there, including [Creating a Sysprep Image Library for Virtual PC](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Creating-Sysprep-Image-Library-Virtual-PC.html) and [Migrating a real PC to Virtual PC#](http://flimflan.com/blog/MigratingARealPCToVirtualPC.aspx).

Comment: Did you try this, install XP mode (all 3 parts) on the new PC, then copy the image file from the old PC and overwrite the default one on the New PC?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully moved a virtualbox and a vmware image with no problems at all simply by copying the files from one computer to the other.

My only suggestion is to make sure both computers are using the EXACT same version of virtual xp.

Comment: VMWare is not feasible. The issue is that a client has XP Mode on his home computer and I am trying to duplicate a problem that I cannot duplicate on my machine. He does not have VMWare. He has an old FoxPro application running in XP mode that works on his machine and not on any of mine (VMWare or XP Mode on my machine).

Comment: @Investor5555 If possible, the best option would be to remote into his computer.  That way no duplication is required and you can see the original issue.

Comment: I cannot do development easily remotely as it requires coordinating with him when he is not using the computer and enables logmein, which means I cannot work if he is using the machine. I want to simply make a copy of the machine and work on it on mine.